# How to use JWT access token from salesforce with azure data factory?

Tags: azure, oauth, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am creating a app on azure and I am using `azure data factory` as a data integration tool, in my app I want to retrieve data from `salesforce` using the `access token` that I generated, the access token was generated by asking the system admin in my app to add his `client Id` and `app secret` of a connected app that he creates for my app and then my app uses server-to-server `oauth` to generate this access token.

However when I configure the salesforce linked service in azure data factory, it asks me for `username`, `password` and optional `security token` as mentioned in this link

[salesforce configuration from microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?tabs=data-factory).

Is the username and password the same as client Id and app secret used to generate the access token ? and if no, how can I use them to integrate with salesforce or there is no way but using another flow.

**note:** I don't know what is the flow that used username + password with security token.

I just don't want to rewrite my code just for this, so any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Microsoft uses username/password flow to generate the access token with salesforce, I don't know why they didn't use another flow because OAuth says that this flow is not recommended for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the username and password should be the credentials of a Salesforce User which will be the one that the system will use to establish the context user. It is common to create an "Integration User" for this purpose in Salesforce.

So basically, the username and password should be the credentials of an active Salesforce User.

Comment: ok so the admin will create an integration user and provide those credentials to my system ? but why using the username/password flow ? isn't this unsafe and not recommended by oAuth community , why microsoft implement it ?

Comment: I don't know much about Microsoft Integration but yes, the fields that are required right there in the documentation that you shared are the username and password for an integration user in Salesforce.

Regarding the auth flow, if you are using a JWT Oath 2.0 flow, you would not need a password as it is not required in the process (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5&language=en_US) so not sure about which flow is using Microsoft behind the scenes.

Comment: Apparently, Microsoft is using the uername/password flow to generate the JWT, this flow requires username, password, client Id and App Secret. I was confused because you can generate a JWT with another flow that only requires username and client Id. so didn't see the need for the username/password flow. anyway, thank you for your answer.